# The correct way to figure out how to solve my "forgot password" screen

Tags: password

My client says that is mandatory to send a code, so the developers suggest this screen where you have "mail field" for the code to be send, but besides that you have "code field". Both of them with his own cta's.
I don't want to have 2 cta's in the same screen, really don't want to and I came up with this "solution?".

[image]

My question is:

¿How many UX axiomas am I tearing apart with a screen like this?
and...
How can I make the "forgot password" experience less stressfull for users counting on the client demands?

Save me from my suffering please.

Btw, I sent that screens to garbage and came up with something else (yeah, I copied it from instagram)

[image]

Comment: (Just commentary, so I'll leave this here...) I like the two screens as it isolates the concerns and thus keeps the user more focused. It also makes sense because the code may take some time to arrive in the user's inbox, so separating this second step makes sense. However, "Done" doesn't sound like the appropriate word for either of these screens--it doesn't describe the action that the user is triggering. "Send" seems more appropriate for the first one, and "Submit", "Sign in", "Authenticate", "Continue" all seem better than "Done" for the second screen. Just my opinion.

Comment: You totally right @maxathousand, I'm leaving that for the very end, but I will take your suggestions, thanks a lot!

Comment: A problem is that the existence of a shortcut for users with a code is not visible. I prefer @maximOrlovsky's solution for that reason.

Answer (score 3):

I agree, your solution looks complicated. 
Did you think about a wizard?

For example:

[image]

Comment: Agreed. This solution is cleaner and more usable.

Comment: I REALLY like this solution, I'll try to make something like this.
Oh man...the PO gonna hate me.
Btw, i made a change, please check it out too if you can

Comment: @FedeCrespo your update is fine but use more descriptive button titles. Not just "Done".

Comment: nice and clean solution

Comment: @MaximOrlovsky thanks a lot! you save my life for real